# How to double digits using sed command in Unix?

Tags: regex, unix, sed, command

I'm new to the Unix sed command and I would like to know how to double the first digit in a string?

Suppose we have a string "F0o", How do I double the first digit in the string?

I tried `echo f0o | sed s/0/00/`, giving `f00o`,
but this will only work for 0s. If the string is "f12o" the output should be `f112o`, simply doubling the first digit in the string.

Is there a command where I can specifically target digits only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know how to double the first digit in a string

You could say:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/&&/' filename
```

This would print the first digit in a line two times.

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]/&&/' <<< "f12o"
f112o
```